# Checking update in database with ESQL without loop

Tags: sql-server-2008, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I can't solve one problem. I am working with IBM WebSphere and my task is the following:

I have a table in database ( SQL Server 2008 ) with only One record - ID and First Name.

I have Input node -> Compute node -> Compute node 2 -> Output node

In the first compute node I need to check that, if in the database table, the First Name is John ( for example ). If it is John, then I need to stop the message there while the name in the database, is different from John. But instead of loop, I need to solve that without loop, because if I use loop in every iteration, the code will check in the database and will be slowly. Can someone help me with that problem? I need to check in database a few times, not every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the loop then enter the query something like

```
SELECT id FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE First_Name='John'
```

if the record returns any data then stop the message there. Otherwise continue.